# Script Task is not working in visual-studio-2017 (SSDT)

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools, script-task, ssis-2017

Script task is strange, it's not working. 
It always says compile error or fails even when I just add some comment!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved after upgrading SSDT to version 15.9.10